# How to populate an dropdownlistfor from database in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

As the title says I'm looking for some help in that task, I've read many tutorials about it but none of them can solved my problem which is how to load a `dropdownlistfor` from database. By far, I got the following code:

```
**LNClientes():**

public List<ENDistrito> DistritoListar()
{
    return new ADClientes().DistritoListar();
}

**ADClientes():**

public List<ENDistrito> DistritoListar()
        {
            Database oDatabase =                      DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conexionBD"]);
            DbCommand odbcommand = oDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("USP_SEL_DISTRITOS");

            List<ENDistrito> lista = new List<ENDistrito>();
            using (IDataReader reader = oDatabase.ExecuteReader(odbcommand))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    lista.Add(new ENDistrito(reader));
            }
            return lista;
        }

**Controller:**

 public ActionResult Registrar()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Resources.Language.Title_Page_MC_C;
            var ListaDistrito = new LNClientes().DistritoListar();
            ViewBag.ObtenerDistrito = new SelectList(ListaDistrito, "IdDistrito", "DescripcionDistrito");
            return View();
        }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistritoCliente)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DistritoCliente,(SelectList)ViewBag.ObtenerDistrito,"--Seleccione--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistritoCliente)
        </div>
```

Till this point everything is ok, when i open that form the `dropdownlistfor` works but when i submit the form i got the following message:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'DistritoCliente'.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or how could i solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Alex

Comment: How come you're using a data reader when you're just reading all your data into a list at one time?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849341/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key solve your problem?

Comment: i followed the article and still have not solve my problem ~ i changed some things like in controller im doing this: ViewData["Distritos"] = new SelectList(new LNClientes().DistritoListar(), "IdDistrito", "DescripcionDistrito"); but the problem still is the declaration of the dropdownlist which is @Html.DropDownListFor(Model=> Model.DistritoCliente,((SelectListItem)ViewData["Distrito"])) but it throws error of arguments, any other idea to solve it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How I commonly build my dropdowns are like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field, PathToController.GetDropDown())
```

and then in your controller have a method built like this

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDown()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lm = (call database);
        foreach (var temp in lm)
        {
            ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = temp.name, Value = temp.id });
        }
        return ls;
    }
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: What is PathToController?

Comment: put in your controller name and type ctrl-.  that will bring in the full path to your controller (project, area, contoller, something like that)

Comment: Glad to help.  would you mind marking my answer as the correct answer?

Comment: I forgot a thing, what about if want to display a label which says "Choose an item"?

Comment: one of the options for the dropdownlistfor is that first item in the dropdown.  I don't remember which item in the list it is.  It might just be ... GetDropDown(), "Choose an item")

Answer (score 4):

Controller:

```
ViewBag.States = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");

View: (In your view write the code for dropdown like this)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Address.StateID,ViewBag.States as SelectList,"--Select State--")
```

--> Here Address in one of the tables in my database having StateID as one of its properties

This one worked perfectly for me.. Try it!!