# How do I put list of BrandNames from Database in a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to put a list of medical product *brand names* in a *dropdown list* on my edit.cshtml file using `Html.DropDownListFor()`.  I am trying to use the Html helper properly but my efforts have been unsuccessful.  Model.BrandSelectListItem is an IEnumerable that is supposed to go into the DropDownList.

Also, I don't understand why I need to reference the model as 'model' in the lambda expression, but as 'Model' in the second argument of the following code segment:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandName, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
```

when executing the code, I receive the following run-time error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'BrandName' is of type
>   'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Here are some classes that may be relevant to this error:

### MedicalProduct

```
public class MedicalProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // is a foreign key
    public Nullable<int> BrandID { get; set; }
}
```

### MedicalProductViewModel

```
public class MedicalProductViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> BrandID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="[Generic]")]
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrandSelectListItem { get; set; }
}
```

### MedicalProductController

```
public class MedicalProductController : Controller
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db = new MvcMedicalStoreDb();

    //
    // GET: /MedicalSupply/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        MedicalProduct medicalProduct = _db.Products.Find(id);
        if (medicalProduct == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var viewModel = GetMedicalProductViewModel(medicalProduct);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public MedicalProductViewModel GetMedicalProductViewModel(MedicalProduct product)
    {
        var mapper = new MedicalProductMapper(_db);

        return mapper.GetMedicalProductViewModel(product);            
    }
}
```

### MedicalProductMapper

```
public class MedicalProductMapper
{
    private MvcMedicalStoreDb _db;

    public MedicalProductMapper(MvcMedicalStoreDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public MedicalProductViewModel GetMedicalProductViewModel(MedicalProduct source)
    {
        MedicalProductViewModel viewModel = new MedicalProductViewModel();
        var dbBrands = _db.Brands.ToArray();

        viewModel.ID = source.ID; 
        viewModel.Name = source.Name;
        viewModel.Price = source.Price;
        viewModel.BrandID = source.BrandID;
        if (viewModel.BrandID != null)
            viewModel.BrandName = dbBrands.SingleOrDefault(b => b.ID == source.BrandID).Name;

        var queryBrands = from b in dbBrands
                          select b;

        // BrandSelectListItem is 'null' before this assignment statement executes. 
        // and Stays null after the statement executes, why?
        viewModel.BrandSelectListItem = queryBrands as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

### Edit.cshtml

```
@model MvcMedicalStore.Models.MedicalProductViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>MedicalProduct</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BrandName, Model.BrandSelectListItem)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: see my answer here on how to build the dropdown list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963618/how-to-populate-an-dropdownlistfor-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-4/18965261?noredirect=1#comment28017688_18965261

Comment: I edited my answer, are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, I don't understand why I need to reference the model as 'model'
>   in the lambda expression, but as 'Model' in the second argument of the
>   following code segment:

You don't need to reference it as model in the lambda expression.  The first part of the lambda (before the => symbol) you are just specifying your parameters and you can name them whatever you want

```
anything => anything.BrandName
```

would work the same as using `model` in place of `anything`

The lambda expression in this case you can think of it as a method that looks like this

```
TProperty GetPropertyYouWantToCreateADropdownFor(MedicalPropertyViewModel model)
{
    return model.BrandName
}
```

As for the dropdown, here is a good post explaining how to create a dropdown

[How to write a simple Html.DropDownListFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057873/how-to-write-a-simple-html-dropdownlistfor)

**Edit**

I plugged in your all your code except your mapper, and just made a little fake implementation of your ViewModel.  Your code worked fine.

Here's what I used for my fake controller

```
 var viewModel = new MedicalProductViewModel
 {
     BrandID = 12,
     BrandName = "Some Brand",
     ID = 6,
     Name = "Some Name",
     Price = 12.27,
     BrandSelectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>()
     {
           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Item 1", Value = "1"},
           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Item 2", Value = "2"}
     }
 };

 return View(viewModel);
```

So seeing that this worked, the only thing I can guess is that your problem lies in your Mapper, can you give an example of what `viewModel.BrandSelectListItem` equals after you get data from the database?  Does throwing in fake data work for you?

**Edit 2:**

queryBrands has to be compatible with `SelectListItem` if your going to cast it into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

You can modify your existing

```
var queryBrands = from b in dbBrands
                      select b;
```

to something like

```
var queryBrands = dbBrands.Select(b => new SelectListItem() 
                                 {
                                     Text = b.PropertyWithWhatYouWantToDisplay,
                                     Value = b.PropertyYouWantAsTheValue,
                                     Selected = //true if you want this item selected, false otherwise
                                 });
```

Comment: I've updated the class named `MedicalProductMapper` in my question with a `//comment` that says what the debugger shows `BrandListSelectItem` is equal to.  The comment says: "BrandSelectListItem is 'null' before this assignment statement executes. and stays null after the statement executes, why?"  Refer to the class for the location of the problem assignment statement.

Comment: Most likely because your trying to cast queryBrands into an ``IEnumberable`` of ``SelectListItem``.  ``SelectListItem`` has 3 properties, `Selected`, `Text`, and `Value` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.108).aspx). I just added a 2nd edit.

Comment: Also: I tried inserting your fake `List<SelectListItem>()` and that worked.