# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key '[0].ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have seen various solutions to this issue, including this one: [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849341/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)>

But I haven't been able to solve my issue.

My view model contains a list of records which are updated on post.  I am able to populate the list of items, including the select menu, on page load.  But if there is a model error, and I return View(model), I receive this error:

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key '[0].ClinicID'

I understand the selected item is coming back as null in the model, but I can't figure out what I am missing.

Controller:

```
ClinicListDB = db.Clinic.Where(p => (p.ClinicActive == "Yes").ToList();

model = from workday in combinedDateList   
        from npcals in db.NPCalendar.Where(x => x.NPCalDate == workday && x.NPID == NPID).Include(x => x.Clinics).DefaultIfEmpty()            
        from ts in db.Timesheets.Where(x => x.TSDate == workday && x.NPID == NPID).Include(x => x.Clinics).Distinct().DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ViewModel
{
    ClinicName = ts != null ? ts.Clinics.ClinicName : npcals != null ? npcals.NPCalLocation : "TBD", 
    ClinicType = ts != null ? ts.Clinics.ClinicType : npcals != null ? npcals.Clinics.ClinicType : "",
    ClinicID = ts != null ? ts.ClinicID : npcals != null ? npcals.ClinicID : 453,
    ClinicList = ClinicListDB.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
       Value = c.ClinicID.ToString(),
       Text = c.ClinicName + " | " + c.ClinicCity,
       Selected = c.ClinicID == (ts != null ? ts.ClinicID : npcals != null ? npcals.ClinicID : 453)}).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList(),                 
    }
    ...(etc)...
 }).ToList()
```

View

```
foreach (var i in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].ClinicID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)i.ClinicList, new { @class = " form-control input-sm" })
}
```

On ModelState.Error

```
return View(model);
```

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key '[0].ClinicID'

I have tried moving the list data into ViewBag, and that didn't help. I abbreviated my code to make it easier to read.  Let me know if I left something out.  Thank you.

Comment: Because you did not repopulate the SelectList (`ClinicList`) before returning the view in the POST method so it was `null`

Comment: Note also `ClinicList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so there is no need to cast it (although its not clear what `i` in `i.ClinicList` is)

Comment: I do the populate ClinicListDb again, but how can I populate the select for each item in the list (keeping the clinic that was already selected)?  I am populating everything in the view model on 'get', do I need to repopulate the whole view model within the (!ModelState.IsValid)?

Comment: I am populating i.ClinicList for each line item within the view model (selecting the appropriate clinic per line item).  Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: You need to repopulate `ClinicList` in the POST method before you use `return View(model);`

Comment: Your view code is a bit confusing and if the view is `@model List<ViewModel>` then the loop should be something like `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ClinicID, Model[i].ClinicList, new { ... }) }`

Comment: Also suggest your read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407811/mvc5-razor-html-dropdownlistfor-set-selected-when-value-is-in-array/37411482#37411482)

Comment: Note also that setting the `Selected` property in `SelectListItem` is pointless (its ignored when using the `DropDownListFor()` method) so you can delete the `Selected = c.ClinicID == (ts != null ? ts.ClinicID .....` line of code

Comment: OK - I have it now.  my issue was the repopulating of the Clinic on error.  Thank you for your help on all the issues that I had.