# Dropdownlist Eror

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building my first MVC application, and for some reason I am not able to make this work:

```
@Html.DropDownList("employeeData", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.employeeData, 
    new { @class="form-control" })
```

and this my controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ViewSchedule(MultipleViewModel filterData, string employeeData)
{
    var id = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
    var profile = new ProfileInfoClient();
    var profileInfo = await profile.FindByID(id.TenantID);
    IEnumerable<ScheduleModels> scheduleData = null;

    var schedule = new ScheduleClient();
    scheduleData = await schedule.ScheduleList(
        employeeData,
        filterData.ViewSchedule.StartDate,
        filterData.ViewSchedule.EndDate, 
        id.SiteID,
        id.TenantID);

    MultipleViewModel result = new MultipleViewModel{
        profileInfoModels = profileInfo,
        ScheduleModelsList = scheduleData
    };
    return View("Index",result);                            
}
```

and this is error message

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'employeeData'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'xxx'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849341/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're not actually setting ViewBag.employeeData in your controller action

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you have ...

```
string employeeData
```

Then you go in to the view and do ...

```
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.employeeData
```

It looks like you need to add more code to your controller that does something like ...

```
// populate this properly from Db or something
ViewBag.employeeData = new List<SelectListItem>();
```