# How to save a value from a dropdownlist with two tables in MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I am very new to programming, so I apologize for my low knowledge (and my bad English too). I also use the Entity Framework.

I looked a couple of posts which seems to have the same Problem, but none of them helped me to fix the Problem in my current situation.

I have to Tables/Models in MVC ( i used Code First). The first Model is "Article"

I tried this in the HttpPost Articles/Create in the Articles Controller.

```
public ActionResult Create( Article article)
    {
 var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Category item in categories)
        {
            categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.Name,
                Value = item.CategoryId.ToString()
            });
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "CategoryId", "Name");
        article.SearchOffers = SearchOffers;
```

Now i get the error when i try to save the article: The value "(id of the selected category)" is not valid. What can I do? Thank you very much for your help.

```
 public class Article
    {
    public virtual int ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }


    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual string Location { get; set; }

    public virtual string Company { get; set; }

    public string SearchOffers { get; set; }

    public string Selling { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public virtual string CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string ContactPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}


public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category>Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The second Model is the Category:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, the Article Table/Model is connected with the Category Table/Model

```
public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

Now here is my Problem, i know how to present the Categories in the Create View, by using a ViewBag which I Created in the ArticlesController.

```
            var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Category item in categories)
        {
            categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.Name,
                Value = item.CategoryId.ToString()
            });
        }
        ViewBag.Category = categoryList;


        return View();
```

The Create View has a DropDown List for representing the Categories.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

But I don't know, how to save the selected categorie. 
I always gt the error : **There is no ViewData-Element of the Type "IEnumerable with the key Category**
I appreciate any help, for my Problem.

**

### EDIT

**
I tried this in the HttpPost of the Articles/Create in the Articles Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create( Article article)
    {
 var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> categoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Category item in categories)
        {
            categoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.Name,
                Value = item.CategoryId.ToString()
            });
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "CategoryId", "Name");
            article.SearchOffers = SearchOffers;
```

Now i get the error when I try to save the Article: The value "(id of the selected category)" is not valid  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkfj.png). What can I do? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849341/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I tried to use the Information in the entry, but it dosen't fixed my problem.

Comment: Which line throws "invalid value" error? Please explain your problem in detailed manner, include exception stack trace if necessary.

Comment: Hey Tetsuya, thank you for your answer. I got this message in the Browser. I don't get the exeption when I am debugging the code. It only appears, when i try to save a created article in the Browser. I posted a picture above. You can also use this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkfj.png.