# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#

I'am try to create a create ActionResult To y Pokemon App In Mvc and i got the error :

> "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key".

I have 2 models: `pokemon` and user which also is foreign Key as an Owner in `pokemon` class.

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(Pokemon pokemon)
 {
    return View(pokemon);
 }
```

Model:

Pokemon Class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[ForeignKey("Owner")]
public int OwnerID { get; set; }
public User Owner { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
public PokemonType Type { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public string Picture { get; set; }
```

User Class:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string UserName { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Adress { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
```

HTML: This is When The Exception Occured In The Html

```
 @Html.DropDownList("OwnerID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

What Should I do To Solve This problem?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you.

Comment: you're not passing any options to give the dropdown list, this will be the second parameter (you're currently passing in null)

Comment: @igal priav, Whats wrong with the answer? why you have removed the green check from my answer. Are you facing any problem? Let me know if you face any problem. I shall help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'xxx'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849341/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not passing any `SelectList` for the Owner `DropDownList` in your `Create` view. So pass Owner `SelectList` for Owner `@Html.DropDownList` as follows:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create()
 {   
     var userList =  _dbContext.Users.ToList();
     ViewBag.OwnerSelectList = new SelectList(userList, "ID", "UserName");
     return View();
 }
```

Then your `@Html.DropDownList` should be as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("OwnerID", (SelectList)ViewBag.OwnerSelectList,"Select Owner", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```